# Optimal route between any two points in a planar graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, 3d, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry

I am after one algorithm that finds the optimal route between any two points in a floor plan (planar graph). I have attached image to illustrate what I want to achieve. In the image, the goal is to connect the hollow point to any other point and minimize intersections at the same time (no intersection in this case).

[image]

in the image above, let's say I also want to connect blue to grey and purple to green, this would introduce an intersection and its what I want to avoid.

So, I just want an algorithm that find the optimal route between any two points in the planar graph, by optimal I mean shortest route with minimum intersections. would be really grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction to make a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for has seen considerable research in VLSI circuit design and is called Routing (in that context).

This does not have a small answer as there are numerous considerations based on design requirements. Some starting points can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)).